# textbox value getting reset in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, webkit

I have a pagination functionality, where the user can either enter page number OR use arrows (< or >) to navigate the results..

Now here is the scenario where I am having issue in Safari;
 1. Say I enter "3" in the page number textbox (i.e. to directly go to page 3)
 2. I press Enter

The result is that in Safari, even though it takes me to page 3, the number in page number textbox also shows "3" momentarily and then resets to "1"

Now I want to know why does this reset back to 1..It always resets to 1, no matter which page number I go to..

I am really sorry that I won't be able to provide the complete code (both bcoz of security issues and it being huge)...But all I can tell is that internally, it uses DWR, AJAX, jQuery..

Also as a hint; When I press Enter, it gets all the data for that page from the server, shows it completely and as soon as it is done, it resets the textbox to 1..i.e. to the initial value specified in the HTML code..So is there some default event taking place in Safari, which I need to prevent..

Comment: Sorry can't think of anything that may cause this. I'm afraid you'll need some form of code or example for others to be able to help you. (PS: what other browsers/versions have you tried where this does work ok?)

Comment: This works fine in IE...not in FF/Safari..For the code, all I can say is mainly it uses textValue = $("#paging_textbox").val(); to get the value, but there is no code where it is setting this to 1...So not sure why Safari resets this to 1..

Comment: Also just to give more hint, when I press Enter, it gets all the data for that page from the server, shows it completely and as soon as it is done, it resets the textbox to 1..i.e. to the initial value specified in the HTML code..

Comment: Oooh, a riddle! So am I right that now it's broken on all major browsers, but IE? Solution 1: DON'T set it back to 1 in your code. :) Solution 2: In case it's using ajax to get the data AND the input field is wrapped in a form, make sure the form doesn't submit when you hit enter.

Comment: 1. It is working on all browsers except Safari 2. For the texbox, I am only using <input> i.e. there is no enclosing form used..I access textbox via ID...

But you seem to be going in the right direction when you say form doesn't submit...But only thin, there is no form that I am using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you stepped through your code to make sure you didn't miss your resetting your own variable to 1? It has happened before to the best of us.